# Play gif once on click and change back

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, getelementbyid

I have an HTML file with a gif of rain and a button that triggers an audio that sounds like thunder. I have a thunder.gif that i would like to play once when the thunder audio is triggered by the button, and then return to the original rain gif.

Right now i have a startAudio() function that creates the audio and one playGif() function where this is the only content

```
document.getElementById("theImage").src="thunder.gif";
```

These are both put in a third function called playThunder() which is called once the button is pressed. However, I don't know how to go back to rain.gif which used to be "theImage" once the thunder.gif is finished playing. I only want the gif to play once and then replace the content of "theImage" with rain.gif again. If I make the function

```
 function thunderGif(){
  document.getElementById("theImage").src="thunder.gif";
  document.getElementById("theImage").src="rain.gif";
}
```

So it will iterate through thunder.gif and then play rain.gif after, it just overrides and doesn't play thunder.gif at all for some reason

Comment: because you change the src right away. There is no delay between those lines. You would have to introduce that delay be coding something. Also there is no way to know when the gif is done,,,,,

Answer (score 1):

Use something like  [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to properly time the src changes based on gif animation length

So you can schedule the src change and avoid the immediate src change in your current `thunderGif()`. Try

```
function thunderGif(){
  document.getElementById("theImage").src="thunder.gif";
  setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("theImage").src="rain.gif"; }, 3000);
  //assuming thunder.gif animation length is 3 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an unorthodox use of a `<video>` tag:

**HTML**

1. Assign the url of MP3 file to `[src]` (video tags have no problem playing audio files)
2. Assign the url of rain GIF to `[poster]`

**JavaScript**

See comments in **Demo**

---

#### Demo

```js
/*
- Reference and register click event to <video>
- Click on <video> to call event handler function storm()
*/
document.querySelector('video').onclick = storm;

// Event handler always passes Event Object (event)
function storm(event) {
  // Reference the tag user clicked
  const clicked = event.target;
  // Define both GIFs
  const rain = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/Wmp1EOzVybWd13s5DB/giphy.gif';
  const lightning = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/3otPoT1atQUL9KIta0/giphy.gif';
  
  // Play MP3 file
  clicked.play();
  // Change the [poster] from rain to lightning GIF
  clicked.poster = lightning;
  /*
  - Change the [poster] from lightning to rain GIF after
    5 seconds which is the time duration of the MP3
  */  
  setTimeout(function() {
    clicked.poster = rain;
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
video {
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
  height: 180px;
  background: rgba(1, 10, 20, 0.9);
  object-fit: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<video src='https://glsec.s3.amazonaws.com/mp3/thunder.mp3' poster='https://media.giphy.com/media/Wmp1EOzVybWd13s5DB/giphy.gif'></video>
```